# how can I get a cell value from a header name in a dataset with one row

Tags: c#, asp.net, header, dataset, cell

I have a table and I want to get specific column from my dataset my table only has one row.

[image: Here is a image of what my table]

Here is my code

```
private DataSet Ds = new DataSet();

public DataSet GetDataSet(string Query)
{
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter Da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Query, conn);
            Da.Fill(Ds);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    return Ds; //See image
}

public string getDataCellString(string headerName)
{
    return "";//I want to get cell from heder name
}
```

Here is my question: **How can I get a cell value from a header name**?

Comment: From where do you expect to call `getDataCellString` ?

Comment: I expect to call getDataCellString from a aspx.cs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one row you can:

```
public string getDataCellString(string headerName)
{
    return Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][headerName].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["headerName"].ToString();